# How to resolve error "-.-" and not able to take pictures on an Olympus OM-D E-M10?

Tags: troubleshooting, olympus, error, olympus-omd

I'm getting this error on my Olympus OM-D E-M10 and I can't take any pictures:

[image]

Comment: Do you know which bit in the picture is indicating the error? I can't see anything *obviously* wrong.

Comment: there is nothing above the sentence mentioning "above".

Comment: Is the `-.-` at the bottom supposed to be a lens aperture? In which case this would mean that there is no lens or the lens is not detected (bad contacts in the mount, or defective lens or lens not supported, or added with a mount converter). This could also be the reason for `MF`. There could be some setting to allow taking pictures despite this (legacy/full-manual lenses).

Comment: Assuming it is the `-.-`... did this just start happening? Did anything happen immediately before the error started? Does it happen with multiple lenses?

Comment: @ths how about some [slack](https://photo.stackexchange.com/conduct) for a newcomer?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Photo.SE. I took the liberty of making the title of your question specific. "How to correct **this**?" could literally refer to anything, after all. Hopefully this should help drive answers that might solve your problem. If you think my edit made your question worse, you can revert it if you like. =)

Comment: @xenoid, I say post that [as an answer not a comment](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/please-put-your-answers-in-the-answers-section-even-if-theyre-short).

Answer (score 3):

Start with the usual suspects:

- Turn off the camera and remove the battery. Let the camera sit overnight. Replace with a fully charged battery, turn the camera on, and see if the problem still manifests itself.
- Remove the lens. Try a different lens. Try the same lens on a different body. Clean the lens contacts on the lens and on the camera body.
- Reset all camera settings to the "factory default" settings. Some cameras require resetting at more than one place in the menu to reset everything.
- If nothing above works, refer it to Olympus authorized service.

Answer (score 1):

Is the  `-.-` at the bottom supposed to be a lens aperture? In which case this would mean that there is no lens or the lens is not detected (bad contacts in the mount, or defective lens or lens not supported, or added with a mount converter). This could also be the reason for MF. There could be some setting to allow taking pictures despite this (legacy/full-manual lenses).